# How to form a string out of multiple chars in a for loop

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, char, chars

The first part of my code is used to receive a single string input from the user and replace certain characters in that word using string class member functions. This part was easy for me to figure out, but I can't seem to figure out how to form a new string out of these changed characters since I will need to use this string for further manipulation later on in my code.

This is problematic since the for loop outputs single char variables that can't be manipulated as a single string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
string word;
char letter;
int i;
cout << "Enter a word: ";
cin >> word;
cout << "\n";
    for ( i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    {
        if ( word.at(i) == 'e')
        {
            word.at(i) = '3';
        }
        if ( word.at(i) == 'i' )
        {
            word.at(i) = '1';
        }
        if ( word.at(i) == 'x' )
        {
            word.at(i) = '*';
        }
        cout << word.at(i);
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

As my code currently stands, a user might, for example, input the string "cheese" and receive the output ch33s3. However this output is not a string; it is an assortment of chars without a space to separate them. I can't continue my code any further with my for loop output remaining as it currently is.

Edit: I realize now that I already have what I need, but confused myself into thinking the scope wouldn't apply outside my for loop. Thanks for the quick and easy answers.

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to be?

Comment: I want the output to remain as it is in appearance, just in the form of a string, rather than a bunch of chars. So in my example, I'd still want an output of ch33s3, but have this saved as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable *word* contains the altered string and can be manipulated as such. It appears that you already have what you need.

Also - you may already know this - but you don't need the "at" function to accomplish what you're doing here. You can index the string like an array. For example:

```
word[i] = 'e';
cout << word[i];
```

Comment: Just checked my code and you're exactly right, not sure why I didn't realize that myself. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Could you select my answer as the correct one, please? Or at least "Vote Up" it if you can?

Comment: @user3366885 _'I didn't realize that myself.'_ Though don't miss out the other answers explaining in more depth what's going on, and give points about your original intends and understandings.

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty much done already:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
string word;
char letter;
int i;
cout << "Enter a word: ";
cin >> word;
cout << "\n";
    for ( i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    {
        if ( word.at(i) == 'e')
        {
            word.at(i) = '3';
        }
        if ( word.at(i) == 'i' )
        {
            word.at(i) = '1';
        }
        if ( word.at(i) == 'x' )
        {
            word.at(i) = '*';
        }
    }
    cout << word << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, your work is already done for you. Your variable "word" would hold the value "ch33s3" after the loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

> However this output is not a string

Did you mean to use `std::ostringstream` instead of `std::cout` to receive the results?

The `word.at(i) = xxx;` statements already manipulated the `word` string, and you have it.

Here's a sample to show how to get a `std:string` result, without manipulating `word` directly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string word;
    char letter;
    int i;
    std::cout << "Enter a word: ";
    std::cin >> word;

    std::ostringstream leetWord;
    for ( i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
        if ( word[i] == 'e') {
            leetWord << '3';
        }
        else if ( word[i] == 'i' ) {
            leetWord << '1';
        }
        else if ( word[i] == 'x' ) {
            leetWord << '*';
        }
        else {
            leetWord << word[i];
        }
    }

    // Here you can refer to the ostringstream::str() function to 
    // get a string
    std::string theWantedString = leetWord.str();
    std::cout << word << " => " << theWantedString << std::endl;
}
```

See the [working sample](http://ideone.com/jJm6bg).